# How can I make an invisible and so I can select through it

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a plane I'm using for shading, It works but I still see it and can select it, I'm gonna need to select the items in a set and I can't click through it. It's not a huge deal as I can obviously just turn my view but I fear it may cause problems in the future. Is there any way to make it invisible and so I can't select it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Restrict viewport selection

Go to the outliner and press the cursor symbol. The object can't be selected in the 3d viewport anymore, only in the outliner.

[image]

#### Restrict visibility

In the object properties area under **Display**, coose *Wire* as the *Maximum Draw Type*.

[image]

**OR**

Make the object invisible by pressing the eye icon. This is the same operation as selecting in the 3d view and pressing <kbd>H</kbd> to hide it.

[image]

Obviously, it will be made visible again, when <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> is pressed to unhide other objects. And since it is unselectable, we can't even hide it again. An option would be to set a key by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering over the disabled eye icon, or setting a driver by right clicking on the eye icon and selecting *Add Driver > Manually (Create later)*.

[image]
*the keyed property turns yellow, the driven property turns lilac*

Unhiding everything with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> will still unhide the object, but it will disappear again on frameupdate (/ framechange).

#### Store it in another [layer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/layers.html#working-with-layers)

Select the object and press <kbd>M</kbd>, then choose another layer, which you don't use. A drawback of this method is, that we have to enable the layer again, before rendering the scene. Objects in disabled layers don't get included in the render.

[image]