# click a object but yellow outline is not appear

Tags: objects

If i click the hair, shoes, clothes object and yellow outline is appear.

But, click the body object yellow outline is not appear.
why yellow outline is not appear?!

I don't check "only render".

I don't uncheck "little icon about selection".

I don't click "Properties > Object > Display > Transparency"

If you have experience please give me some advice.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, check in the outliner that the object has not  selection disabled (it should have three little icons visible: eye, cursor, camera). See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107561/how-can-i-make-an-invisible-and-so-i-can-select-through-it?s=1|246.7882

Comment: Thanks. m.ardito. But I'm not touch those three little icons. especially cursor. Are you have any other solution? (I modify my post about those three icons.)

Comment: Maybe *Properties > Object > Display > **Transparency*** is enabled.

Comment: Thank you. Leander. comment to me.
but, I'm not click "Properties > Object > Display > Transparency".

Comment: Maybe switch the Outliner to show 'Groups' and check to see if the object in question is part of a group that is set to 'non-select', as an individual object will still show to be selectable.

Answer (score 1):

On the right side (blender shortcut - n key ) is a Display - Outline Selected
[image]